# Passing value from url to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

I have created an a tag in my x.blade.pdp file

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/certificate/pdf/'.$year) }}" class= "text-center">Print Certificate</a>
```

In web.php

```
Route::get('/certificate/pdf/{$year}','PDFController@export_pdf');
```

My Controller

```
public function export_pdf( $year)
```

But when I click on the link the page cannot be displayed. I would like to use the $year in the where clause .

Please I need some assistance

Comment: wy don't just use a get variable like ?year=2018

Comment: change to Route::get('/certificate/pdf/{year}','PDFController@export_pdf');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller function should be like this

```
public function export_pdf( Request $request){
  $year = $request->year;
}
```

Route should be like this

```
Route::get('/certificate/pdf/{year}','PDFController@export_pdf');
```

if the year is optional then route is

```
Route::get('/certificate/pdf/{year?}','PDFController@export_pdf');
```

Answer (score 1):

In `routes/web.php`, define your route much like you have done (I normally put the name also at the end).

```
Route::get('/someroute/route-url/{param1}', 'Directory\ControllerName@controller_function')->name('route-url-name');
```

Then you can describe that route in your view/blade by using its name, and pass the param:

```
{{ route('route-url-name', $param) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the `$` and use: `Route::get('/certificate/pdf/{year}','PDFController@export_pdf');`

in your web.php file.